# Turning character strings red based on reference in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I pulled the following code from Stack Overflow at some point in the past and can't seem to find it again.  I had a similar need for another project so I copy/pasted the code into a new module and now it doesn't work (same reference list).  The portion of the code that causes the error is in bold.  If you delete that part of the code and continuing running,  it completes the job and is accurate.  It is almost like the "If Statement" doesn't close.  The only change between projects was the column the note appears in went from Col G to Col I.  The list of reference strings is 100+, the list of daily notes is around 1000.  All formatting for reference strings and notes is "General" in both the first and second applications.  Any guidance on why this broke would be appreciated.

```
'Pulled from Stack Overflow
'Searches all text in Column 2 on a Sheet for the string located in Column 1
'If found it highlights that text

Dim ThisWB As Workbook
 Dim ThisWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Dim Col1 As Double
Dim Col2 As Double

Dim Col1_rowSTART As Double
Dim Col1_rowEND As Double

Dim Col2_rowSTART As Double
Dim Col2_rowEND As Double

Dim strTest As String
Dim strLen As Integer

'Set up parameter that we know
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ThisWS = ActiveSheet
Col1 = 14 'Words Col N
Col2 = 9 'Comments Col I
'Define Starting Row for each column
Col1_rowSTART = 1
Col2_rowSTART = 1
'Define ending row for each column
Col1_rowEND = ThisWS.Cells(ThisWS.Rows.count, Col1).End(xlUp).Row
Col2_rowEND = ThisWS.Cells(ThisWS.Rows.count, Col2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = Col1_rowSTART To Col1_rowEND
    'make a string out of each cell value in Col1
    strTest = CStr(ThisWS.Cells(i, Col1))
    strLen = Len(strTest)
    'Roll thorugh all of Column 2 in search of the target string
    For y = Col2_rowSTART To Col2_rowEND
        'Check if Col1 string is in Col2 String
        If InStr(CStr(ThisWS.Cells(y, Col2)), strTest) > 0 Then
        **ThisWS.Cells(y, Col2).Characters(InStr(ThisWS.Cells(y, Col2), strTest), strLen).Font.Color 
= vbRed**
        End If
    Next y
Next i
```

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I don't know if this is just how you pasted it into SO, but `=vbRed` is an error. Vba does not compile statements that are split by line-breaks without continuation marks like "_".  `= vbRed` is on its own line and is interpreted as its own statement which would cause a compile error.

Comment: Warcupine:  I receive the Run Time error '13'...Type mismatch.

Comment: Toddleson:  That was just the way the code pasted into SO.  Actual code is on the same line.